# Android error: cannot find symbol variable menu

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

Im creating menu:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.points, menu);

    return true;
}
```

I have xml file in res/menu/points.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="Item" />
</menu>
```

I get error - Error:(27, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable menu

why ?

Clean Rebuild helps - Thanks

Comment: `Clean-Rebuild` at first

Comment: Check if you not imported android.R

Comment: Did Clean Rebuild fix the problem? If so, please either delete the question or add an answer to say that it fixed it and accept it, so people don't come here looking to add an answer in the future.

Comment: I had this problem, because I had a menu.xml file in my .free package by mistake, when I really want to use the menu.xml file from the main package.

Comment: As told by @IntelliJAmiya, cleaning the Build worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and my issue was with the parameter Menu menu. When i first invoked Menu i didn't hit enter to set it to android.view menu, which would explain why yours is saying it doesn't understand the variable. If your not casting it as a menu type for what you're importing it as then it wont understand it as a standalone variable. I hope this helps, we could possible be working on the same tutorial. Good luck either way!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `menu_main.xml` file in menu folder in  `res folder.res>menu>menu_main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```